# Why did this sentence use ”was”?

Tags: grammar

“Captain Fawcett's first passenger was a doctor who flew from Birmingham to a lonely village in the Welsh mountains.”Why this sentence uses”was” instead of”is”?

It says the passenger was a doctor.Why it isn’t state he used to be a doctor,but now he’s not? –

Answer (score 1):

Because that person is no longer a passenger on Capt. Fawcett's plane, so a present tense would not be correct.

He/she *was* a passenger (in the past). The passenger was a doctor at a time in the past; he/she may still be a doctor, but that does not matter.

Comment: But it said the passenger was a doctor.Why it isn’t  state he used to be a doctor,but  now he’s not?

Comment: The passenger was a doctor at a time in the past; he may still be a doctor, but that does not matter.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Morebravethanever   this kind of detail should go in the question.  It should not be in a comment

Comment: This is an example of *tense agreement*